# Find user by using a variable in powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, scripting

This line works.

```
get-aduser -f {name -like '*John*'} | format-Table name,SamAccountName
```

## ===

The following doesn't work. Your help will be greatly appreciated, thank you very much in advance.

```
$name = Read-Host "Enter a First Name or Last Name"  
$uname = "'*" + $name + "*'"   
get-aduser -f {name -like $uname } | Format-Table name, SamAccountName
```

## ===

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the **'** at the end and the start of line 2, like this:

```
$name = Read-Host "Enter a First Name or Last Name"  
$uname = "*" + $name + "*"   
get-aduser -f {name -like $uname } | Format-Table name, SamAccountName
```

Answer (score 1):

Your extra single quotes are not needed and getting included in the search so you end up searching for `'*John*'` instead of `*John*`, so the name should not start and end with `'`

Just change to

```
$uname = "*$name*"
```